# Voice sounds uneven after noise removal?

Tags: audio-recording, noise-reduction, voice, volume, echo

After noise removal my voice sounds uneven if volume is more than 40.There are many ups and downs and also there are echos sort of thingy.

https://clyp.it/sh3t0aoz (with noise removal)
https://clyp.it/jo4zmhlu (without noise removal)

Comment: What are you using for noise removal?

Comment: audacity i used

Answer (score 1):

I think your taking the processing too far.  You shouldn't really think of it as "Noise Removal" but as "noise reduction"  Try reducing the bakground instead of removing it entirely.  Sometimes echos appear when the processing is pushed to far and other times they were always there but masked by the background noise.

Comment: the clip with noise removal(noise reduction) was reduced by 24db....

Comment: ok - that sounds like quite a bit.  Its far from a one size fits all solution.  Most audio cleans up fine with far less reduction and the audio that doesn't will probably sound more natural with less.  Whats the final use for the voice file?

Comment: I m gonna use it for voice over..

Comment: If music is going to be playing with then you can back off the processing quite a bit I'd think.  Maybe take a little more care when recording next time.

Comment: so there's nothing that can be done

Comment: No you can do a lot with it.  I would just go back to the original and apply less noise reduction.  You might be able to use an expander or multibancd compression after the noise reduction to further reduce the noise with giving you artifacts.

Comment: well i used adobe audition and my voice was still normal even after noise reduction...i guess something was wrong with audacity....

Comment: Audition might have better noise reduction tools than audacity. Or it could be a setting.

Answer (score 1):

"Noise removal" is a shot in the dark based on statistics.  Noise is usually a stochastic, random signal, so it has a non-zero chance of matching the model of speech of the noise removal program.  Conversely, speech has a non-zero chance of matching the noise model.  Particularly consonants and specifically fricatives are virtually indistinguishable from noise.

So the more "noise removal" you apply, the more your speech gets affected along with the noise.

The main purpose of noise removal with speech is not to restore the original quality of a signal source but to increase its comprehensibility.  This comes at the cost of musical noise, echoes and other artifacts.

If you want a low-noise recording for a *voice-over*, you don't want the distracting qualities of noise removal: you are almost always better off with a constant noise floor of tolerable loudness.  So try moving closer to your microphone or getting better recording equipment.  You'll likely also want to apply some noise-gating (which is a rather coarse form of noise removal but with less impact on the speech) but of course you'll be better off if you don't have significant noise levels to start with.